# get the position of each row in the query in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a table with two columns:

[id,score]

and I want to retrieve the following result

[position, id ,score]

for example for

```
id    score
1      7
2      3
3      19
```

I want to retrieve

```
pos    id    score
1      3      19
2      1      7
3      2      3
```

How can I do it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query could look something like this:

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘pos’, t.id, t.score from the_table t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r order by score desc limit 10;
```

Edit
The `limit` is totally optional by the way

Answer (score 0):

```
set @pos=0;
select @pos:=@pos+1 as 'pos',id,score
from exampletb 
order by score desc;
```

to get the position you need to use `@pos:=@pos+1`, it will increment as per rows increases and will return the position of the selected row.

and `order by score desc` to get the largest element on the top.

and result of above query as what you wanted

```
pos    id    score
1      3      19
2      1      7
3      2      3
```